# nokia here location api is not working in php

Tags: php, json, api, here-api

I want to get the businesses info from nokia here location api. Below is my code:

```
$NokiaPlaceURL = 'http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id='.APP_ID.'&app_code='.APP_CODE.'&at='.$at.'&q='.$keyword.'&size=10';
        //echo $NokiaPlaceURL; exit;
        $NokiaPlaceURL = file_get_contents($NokiaPlaceURL);
        var_dump($NokiaPlaceURL);exit;
```

It gives the below error. How can I solve this ?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=---&app_code=---&at=40.708322%2C-74.008881&q=food&size=10) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/nokia_here.php on line 29
bool(false)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some HTTP headers for your request. From the API documentation I see that you need to set `Accept` to either `application/json` for data encoded in JSON, or `application/xhtml+xml` for XML data. The header is marked as being optional, however, I suspect that PHP sets its own headers, including `Accept` that does not have the value Nokia's API would expect.

However, as to how you could add headers to a GET request via `file_get_contents`, well, you can use stream contexts. For example:

```
$Options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Accept: application/json'
    )
);

$Context = stream_context_create($Options);
$File = file_get_contents($URL, false, $Context);
```

Comment: The definitive list of HTTP headers can be found in the [Places API documentation](http://developer.here.com/docs/places/topics/http-request-headers.html) The relevant quote is shown below (the emphasis is mine):

_Specifying  `application/json` results in a json response, while
 `xhtml+xml` or equivalent (possible wildcards) results in json-like
HTML._ **Any other values will prompt a 406 response.**

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to link that but with all the frames the closest direct link that doesn't lose the navigation was to the section beginning.